# Tomcat MaxThreads number for production env

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

What is the apt number of maxThreads for tomcat. I see that its 200 by default. Should this be a good number or is it only a sample number given. Was thinking if increasing this number would help in the app to perform better - or take more users accessing the app in parallel. Whats the best number to have for maxThreads

Does this count have anything to do with the H/W configuration - i am running a 8GB RAM 4core processor.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

How long is a piece of string? There is no right answer. 200 is a reasonable place to start but as with any performance tuning it is application specific.

I've known apps that run on a lot smaller hardware than yours easily handle maxThreads of 1500+. Equally, I can think of some apps that run on bigger hardware that use maxThreads of 5.

Measure your performance, change maxThreads and then measure the performance again. That is the only way to tell if a change in maxThreads (up or down) will improve the performance of your system.